# Extra themes - ok or bad?

Tags: themes, security, server-load

I know I am a newbie here, but I'm just wondering, if you keep extra themes in your Wordpress setup, will it add bloat to your site? Can these other themes provide a security risk even if they aren't activated?

I imagine it's best to delete any theme that aren't in use, but I'm noticing a lot of unused themes in other setups, so perhaps it doesn't really matter?

Thankyou!

Comment: If you don't need it, get it off your production server. Extra things are OK for testing and dev environments. You won't know there is a security risk until it's too late.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks! I wonder why Wordpress comes with 3 themes by default then?

Comment: Options are good and people want choices. But if you're set on a single theme and you don't need the rest then get rid of them.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep doing that. Do you know if they add server load at all? I'm guessing not, because they're not processing anything? Just disk space.

Comment: You can only activate one theme at a time, the rest are ignored except when you're looking at all your themes. So yes, disk space.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.wordfence.com/learn/ when you get a chance. Probably some good info there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any extra code on your server is a theoretical security risk. Instead of checking each plugin and theme if they are security risk even if they are not active, it is much easier to just delete them.

This of course should not prevent you from backuping them first in case you will decide that you need them in the future ;)

Comment: Thanks Mark. And for the new word for my dictionary - backuping - we all need more of that!